# Setting image dynamically in a modal without delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to build a timeline for displaying schedule of events on a day. The code for the same is located at https://jsfiddle.net/2r99xu02/2/. Whenever, you click the speaker names, it opens a modal with some info about the speaker with a photograph.

However, the issue I am facing here is that the `img` tag's `src` attribute is set at the time of displaying the modal and it when I open the modal, the image gets set about a second later which does not look very good. Is there anything I can do to ensure that the modal only shows when the `src` attribute has been set.

I am using jquery and w3css

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `load` function from jQuery.

Note: https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/

> **Removed deprecated event aliases**
>
> .load, .unload, and .error, deprecated since jQuery 1.8, are no more. 
>   Use .on() to register listeners.

You say, you use jQuery. Then use it!
I've updated your code a little bit (JS) and added a *span* after the speaker image (HTML).

Please check your html structure and naming. To access elements by its index is bad.
Give classes to your divs, spans etc.

---

The demo is not working, because the images are not available. Please
check this by yourself. This is only an example how you can do it.

```js
const info = {
    'David Anderson': ' David Anderson Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'John Doe': 'John Doe Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'Mark Smith': 'Mark Smith Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'Michael Lee': 'Michael Lee Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'Steve Newman': 'Steve Newman Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
};

function openSpeakerBio() {
    const $name = $(this);

    const name = $name.html().replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gi, ' ');

    const imgName = './' + $name.text() + '.png';

    const $modal = $('#id02');
    const $header = $modal.find('h4');
    const $image = $modal.find('.modal-image');
    const $bio = $modal.find('.bio');
    const $fusionLogo = $('.fusion-logo-1x');

    $header.html(name);
    $bio.find('span').html(info[name]);
    $image.attr('src', imgName);

    $image.on('load', function() {
        $modal.show();
    });

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $fusionLogo.attr('src', '//new.network-data-cabling.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ACCL_Logo.svg');
    });
}

function closeModal() {
    const $modal = $('#id02');

    $modal.hide();
}

$(function () {
    // listen for events
    $('.speaker img').on('click', openSpeakerBio);
    $('.speaker h3').on('click', openSpeakerBio);
    $('.close-modal').on('click', closeModal);
});
```

```css
/* Import */

@import url(./assets/timeline-fonts.css);

/* Variables */


/* Base */

strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.vertical-alignment-helper {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.vertical-align-center {
  /* To center vertically */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bio {
  text-align: justify;
}


/* Timeline */

.timeline {
  border-left: 4px solid #a5a5a5;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1.03em;
  padding: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 100;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.timeline h1,
.timeline h2,
.timeline h3 {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.timeline .event {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline .event:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}

.timeline .event:before,
.timeline .event:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
}

.timeline .event:before {
  left: -170px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  content: attr(data-date);
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  min-width: 120px;
}

.timeline .event:after {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #a5a5a5;
  left: -37.85px;
  background: #313534;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  content: "";
  top: 5px;
}

.width-max {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.middle-modal {
  top: 40%;
}

.speaker {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.speaker img {
  width: 75px;
}

.modal-image {
  margin: 1em 1em 0.25em 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-sand w3-large">


  <div class="w3-container " id="schedule">
    <div class="w3-content width-max ">
      <h4 class="w3-center p2t p1b"><span class="w3-tag w3-wide ">SCHEDULE</span></h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="timeline ">
      <li class="event" data-date="09:30 - 10:00 ">
        <div onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">
          <h3 class="event-title">Registration</h3>
          <p>It is on first come first server basis. Pls hurry</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="event" data-date="10:00 - 10:30 ">
        <div>
          <h3 class="event-title">Introduction</h3>
          <p><strong> Speaker </strong>
            <br />
          </p>
          <div class="speaker">
            <img src="./avatar.png" alt="Boss" class="w3-circle">
            <h3>Michael<br />Lee</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="event" data-date="10:30 - 11:15 ">
        <div>
          <h3 class="event-title">Speech 1</h3>
          <p><strong> Speaker </strong>
            <br />
          </p>
          <div class="speaker">
            <img src="./avatar.png" alt="Boss" class="w3-circle">
            <h3>David<br />Anderson</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="event" data-date="11:30 - 12:15 ">
        <div>
          <h3 class="event-title">Speech 2</h3>
          <p><strong> Speakers </strong>
            <br />
          </p>
          <div class="speaker">
            <img src="./avatar.png" alt="Boss" class="w3-circle">
            <h3>Steve<br />Newman</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="event" data-date="12:30 - 13:15 ">
        <div>
          <h3 class="event-title">Competetion</h3>
          <p><strong> Speakers </strong>
            <br />
          </p>
          <div class="speaker">
            <img src="./avatar.png" alt="Boss" class="w3-circle">
            <h3>Mark<br />Smith</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="event" data-date="14:00 - 14:45 ">
        <div>
          <h3 class="event-title">Prize Distribution</h3>
          <p><strong> Speaker </strong>
            <br />
          </p>
          <div class="speaker">
            <img src="./avatar.png" alt="Boss" class="w3-circle">
            <h3>John<br />Doe</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Modals -->

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal w3-grayscale">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-opacity middle-modal">
      <header class="w3-container w3-khaki w3-display-container">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-khaki w3-display-topright"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span>
        <h4>Register</h4>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container bio">
        <p>Registration link goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
      <div class="vertical-align-center">
        <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-opacity">
          <header class="w3-container w3-khaki w3-display-container">
            <span class="w3-button w3-khaki w3-display-topright close-modal"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></span>
            <h4></h4>
          </header>
          <div class="w3-container bio">
            <img alt="Speaker" class="w3-round modal-image">
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstand correctly you don't want the Modal anmiation. It is set with the class w3-animate-opacity which comes from the w3.css. If you delete that the Modal pops up instantly.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I am looking for. I do want the modal to fade in like it does. But the image in the modal that comes about a second later should already be there when the modal opens

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean the <img alt="Speaker" class="w3-round modal-image"> ? But that doesn't have a delay when I open it.